# asp.net dynamic link in code behind retrieve parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, hyperlink

Sorry for my debutant question and if an answer has already been made. I don't even know how to define my search so can't get any result from my search.

Here it goes.

Iam setting dynamic link in my code behind and want to retrieve the parameter associated to the link that has been clicked.

My aspx.cs :

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, listeMembres> entry in listeEquipesByUser) 
            {
                equipe = dbProvEquipe.find(entry.Key);  
                linkM = new HyperLink();
                linkE = new HyperLink();
                ligne = new TableRow();

                cellule = new TableCell();
                cellule.Text = linkM.NavigateUrl = String.Format("profilConnecteMembre.aspx?idEquipe={0}", equipe.IdEquipe.ToString());
                linkM.Text = "Trouver les membres";
                cellule.Controls.Add(linkM);
                ligne.Cells.Add(cellule);

                cellule = new TableCell();
                cellule.Text = linkE.NavigateUrl = String.Format("profilConnecteEvent.aspx?idEquipe={0}", equipe.IdEquipe.ToString());
                linkE.Text = "Trouver les évènements";
                cellule.Controls.Add(linkE);
                ligne.Cells.Add(cellule);


                tableEquipes.Rows.Add(ligne);
                // Session["idEquipe"] = equipe.IdEquipe.ToString(); 
// need to retrieve the idEquipe where it's been clicked
            }
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: Hyperlinks will redirect to a new page. You would use Request["ParameterName"] to retrieve the data from the query string. If you want to capture user input before a redirect in the code-behind of the current page, then you should create LinkButtons instead.

Comment: Merci !  Thank you ! I did it, with your help.